# How to save to database only that records that is not in database yet?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using flask and I started to use SQLalchemy for my databases. I have a huge list of dictionary something like this:

```
data = [{'id': '3242342342', 'name': 'sfsdfs fsdcd'},
        {'id': '2131231221', 'name': 'sfsddddfs fsdcd'},
        {'id': '3434343544', 'name': 'sfsfdgfddfs fsdcd'},
        {'id': '5465443545', 'name': 'sfsiiiiiiidfs fsdcd'}]
```

and I have a class like this:

```
class Record(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

My task is to process all records from `data` and add them if they are not in the database yet and update if they are. What is a correct way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge function is what you want here.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#unitofwork-merging

```
for elem in data:
  tmp = Record(id=elem['id'], name=['name'])
  session.merge(tmp)
```

And commit sometime later of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on data with for loop, but I am not sure is it best way or not:

```
for elem in data:
    for id, name in elem.items():
        record = Record.query.get(id)
        if record:    
            record.id = id
            record.name = name
        else:
            record = Record(id=id, name=name)
        session.add(record)
```